# Wordpress/Timber/Twig - Trying to output checkbox values

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I have an Advanced Custom Fields repeater (contacts), and each row in the repeater (contact) has a set of checkboxes (groups) and I am simply trying to get the value of each checkbox. I have tried the below, but with no luck. Can anyone help?

```
{% for contact in mc.contacts %}
    {% for group in contact.groups %}
        {{ group.value }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it - it's simply `{{ group }}` when calling the value!

```
{% for contact in mc.contacts %}
    {% for group in contact.groups %}
        {{ group }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```